# Node.js: Foreman + Nodemon behaviour on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js, foreman

After hours of debugging, I finally isolated why my web app was crashing on Windows. An NPM dependency is sometimes logging messages with `console.error`, and this seems to have different behaviours on OSX & Windows when running the *Foreman* + *Nodemon* combo.

Maybe someone with more knowledge of these tools can help shed some light on this?
Here's a simple app to illustrate it:

**app.js**

```
console.log('1');
console.error('2');
console.log('3');
```

Running `nodemon --exec node app.js` works fine on both OSX & Windows 7, and gives the expected output:

```
18 Feb 23:56:25 - [nodemon] v0.6.23
18 Feb 23:56:26 - [nodemon] watching: C:\project
18 Feb 23:56:26 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
1
2
3
18 Feb 23:56:26 - [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Now, wrapping the call using Foreman and a Procfile, it looks like this:

```
# Procfile
app: nodemon --exec node app.js
```

On OSX:

```
> foreman start

23:59:12 app.1  | started with pid 69229
23:59:12 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:12 - [nodemon] v0.7.2
23:59:12 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:12 - [nodemon] watching: /project
23:59:12 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:12 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
23:59:12 app.1  | 1
23:59:12 app.1  | 2
23:59:12 app.1  | 3
23:59:12 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:12 - [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

On Windows:

```
> foreman start

23:59:40 app.1  | started with pid 2624
23:59:40 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:40 - [nodemon] v0.7.2
23:59:40 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:40 - [nodemon] watching: C:\project
23:59:40 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:40 - [nodemon] starting `node app.js`
23:59:40 app.1  | 1
23:59:40 app.1  | 18 Feb 23:59:40 - [nodemon] exception in nodemon killing node
23:59:40 app.1  | exited with code 3
23:59:40 system | sending SIGKILL to all processes
```

The app simply crashes, with no recovery, and then Foreman kills any other process declared in the Procfile.

Any ideas will be appreciated!

*note: I tried a different version of `nodemon` on Windows (6.2.3) with the same results*

Comment: Me too.  I tried rerun as well, with no luck.